# react setValues hook is not working properly

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, setstate, updating

I have an array of files that will be uploading, but I want to change the array of file strings to an array of objects which is working fine. But when I try to update the variable to the new array, it still keeps the old array in its place. My variable is declared as such:

```
const initialState = {
name: '',
description: '',
price: '',
categoryList: [],
category: '',
subcategoriesList: [],
subcategories: [],
countInStock: '',
images: [],
brand: '',
buttonText: 'Add Product',
}
const [values, setValues] = useState(initialState)
```

Now when a user uploads one or multiple images, `images` has the file path to where the file has been uploaded. Works as expected. Now I'm trying to allow for a 'default' image by running the following code before the product is uploaded to the database:

```
let newArray = values.images.map((file) => ({
default: 0,
file: file,
}))
setValues({ ...values, images: newArray })
```

I would think that setting the values with the newArray would replace what was in images at first, but when I console.log the values.images on the next line, I only get the previous images (just the filepath) before I changed it to an object. What am I missing or not doing correctly?

`console.log(values.images)` logs the previous images prior to being changed.

Comment: "when I console.log the values.images on the next line, I only get the previous images" is a bad expectation.  Setting state in react is not instantaneous and will only show on the next rerender.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately)

Answer (score -2):

that is the correct way to change any state

```
let newArray = values.images.map((file) => ({
  default: 0,
  file: file,
}));

setValues((prevValues) => ({
  ...prevValues,
  images: newArray,
}));

// Now if you log values.images, it should contain the updated array.
console.log(values.images);
```

Comment: Did you try to actually run this or the previous code?  This is just a restatement of the original code with your own convention preferences and doesn't address the issue at hand.  You've also made the mistake that `values` will be updated instantaneously when it will not happen until the next rerender

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).